# Overwrite "object managing shared pointer" with new memory C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a simple code which looks like this, which I was experimenting -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class TestClass {
public:
  TestClass(int a, int b) : mA(a), mB(b) {
    std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  ~TestClass() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
private:
  int mA;
  int mB;
};

int main(){

    auto classPtr = std::make_shared<TestClass>(100, 200);

    // Process....

    classPtr = std::make_shared<TestClass>(100, 200);

    return 0;
}
```

I overwrite a shared pointer which already manages an object with new memory. Based on my reading of assignement operator for shared pointer [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D#:~:text=If,the%20owned%20deleter.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D#:%7E:text=If,the%20owned%20deleter.), the previous memory gets destroyed before the new assignment takes place.

So I expect output to be -

```
constructor
destructor
constructor
destructor
```

But the output is -

```
constructor
constructor
destructor
destructor
```

**Question** - I am curious what is happening to the old memory and why it is not de-allocated before the second allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `constructor` is the construction of the first object.

The second `constructor` is the construction of the second object.

The first `destructor` is the destruction of the first object, as part of the assignment to the smart pointer object.

The second `destructor` is the destruction of the second object, when the variable goes out of scope.

The second object must be constructed before an assignment can be made.

---

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
// Construction of first object
auto classPtr = std::make_shared<TestClass>(100, 200);

// Construction of the second object
auto temporary = std::make_shared<TestClass>(100, 200);

// Assignment, causing destruction of the first object
classPtr = temporary;
```

Comment: I see, now I added some prints after the second allocation to create some delay, and I observe what you said, thanks